# creating a scrollable table in Excel with colors

Tags: excel

First off I want to go ahead and apologize, since i am not an experienced Excel user. I've tried searching but couldn't find the right answers.
I've been trying to create a scrollable table in Excel and i found the following link/video

http://www.exceltraining101.com/2013/06/create-a-scrolling-table/

which uses the OFFSET function to create the table. It was easy to follow the steps and i created a similar table. (Since my "Data" sheet contains 200 rows of data, i won't go into details)

Some data on my sheet have colors or color fills but they don't appear in this scrollable list i created. I actually expected that, since the "colors" are not "data" to be transferred.

Is there a way to transfer the data with their colors in the scrollable table using the above method (see link)? Any other suggestions on creating a scrollable table are welcome. Thank you!

Comment: How do the cells receive their color fills? If it can be boiled down to rules, then conditional formatting should do the trick. If it is more arbitrary, then this will be a difficult task.

Comment: It's custom. I choose which ones are colored just to stand out. I guess it's pretty hard to do this without conditional formatting

Comment: Instead of coloring the cell, you could create another column in your source data that is the indicator of when something should be highlighted. That would allow you use conditional formatting on the source table and your scrollable table.